# How to fix "This item is no longer available." error while purchasing ANY in-app product using Play Billing library in android app?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-console, play-billing-library

[image: Play Billing In-App Purchase Error]

Hi,

Users of my app are facing an error (shown above in the image) while trying to purchase ANY in-app product in my app. After a lot of googling and searching around, I could not find out the root cause of the problem.

Things that I have already verified:

- In-App products ids are valid and in sync between app and developer
  console.
- All In-App products are active.
- Verified there is no error in Play Billing library integration. The error displayed in the image is shown by the Play Billing library UI and not by my app.
- Verified there are no issues reported for my developer console payments profile at payments.google.com.

I use my own wrapper library over play billing library. [The library](https://github.com/ankitbatra11/billingr/tree/master/billingr/src/main/java/com/abatra/billingr) is open sourced at github. So, you can take a look at the entire source code [there](https://github.com/ankitbatra11/billingr/tree/master/billingr/src/main/java/com/abatra/billingr).

Kindly, do let me know if any more information is required. I have hit a wall in this one.

Play Billing library version used: `3.0.2`

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this issue on your own? If so, what were returned by getResponseCode and getDebugMessage of BillingResult when this issue happened?

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce. The `getResponseCode` is `OK`.

Comment: Sorry I could not provide you a quick answer. I think this error msg should be displayed when the user tried to exchange their Play Points for an item, but the requested item is not available. But you were seeing this during a normal purchase flow, so I have no idea either. However, I think you might want to check whether the returned SKUDetails from querySkuDetailsAsync matches your expectation in case you were hard coded the price and currency here.

Comment: And I also feel curious that your IAP seems to be an uncomsumable for one-time purchase but not a subscription item, then how could you provide a free trial for it?

Comment: I have got in touch with the Google Play Developer support team and they have told me that it could be related to an issue with my payment account. I am going to fix that and check if that resolves this error.

Comment: I re-entered the payment method in my developer console account and created a new in-app SKU, the purchase flow of which is working fine. For some reason, older active in-app SKU(s) were (and still are) not working.